# Unable to find element in IE8 using selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to run my test in IE8 by using INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS capability. but somehow webdriver tells me element not found. Below is my sample snippet code to reproduce error

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

class IETest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/main/resources/IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
        // WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
        By by = By.name("q");
        System.out.println("Started.");

        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(by);
        ele.sendKeys("test");
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Starting to wait for some time.");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

IE8 - tried on both versions (32-bit as well as 64-bit)
Selenium-java version: 2.44.0, 2.40, 2.39.0
NOTE: Keep your security domains Enabled so that selenium should be able to ignore the security domains.

EDIT: my current internet settings are: 
internet:enabled 
local intranet:enabled 
trusted sites: disabled 
restricted sites:enabled

TIA!!

Comment: If you've set the Protected Mode settings to enabled for all zones, you do not need to use the `INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS` capability.

Comment: How far does your code get? And can you paste the error you get?

Comment: @JimEvans i have added my current internet settings in the question. Also i am behind a network security domain, so can't change the security settings, which is why i was using that capability.

Comment: @SK1 The code runs fine only till sysout("Started"). post that i get NoSuchElementException stating that element cannot be found using name==q locator

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following two capabilities:

```
capabilities.SetCapability("EnableNativeEvents", false);
capabilities.SetCapability("RequireWindowFocus", true);
```

Mine is C#.

Comment: two? where is the second one?

Comment: nope still same error. my current internet settings are: internet:enabled
local intranet:enabled
trusted sites: disabled
restricted sites:enabled